# Apache Spark giving error in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have written a code for SparkSQL. I ran it using Eclipse Neon. It was working fine. When I shifted to IntelliJ Idea, the same code is not running.
Here is the code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();
spark.sql("select survey_response_value from health").show();
```

The exceptions I am getting are:
https://justpaste.it/13tsa
Kindly let me know why I am facing this problem. How I can resolve this? Should I write the code from the start using IntelliJ or is there any mechanism for help?

Comment: `Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.5.1`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38689045/104891, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40957294/104891

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.5.1
```

Basically, Spark uses Jackson version 2.6.5, but there is another dependency you use that puts an older version (2.5.1) of Jackson on the classpath. It is difficult to say why it's different between Eclipse and IntelliJ, but my guess is that they build up the classpath differently, so that with Eclipse the correct version is placed first.

There are several questions about this error on SO, eg:

- [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819763/com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-jsonmappingexception-jackson-version-is-too-old)
- [Jackson version is too old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686318/jackson-version-is-too-old)
- [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.4.3 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957294/com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-jsonmappingexception-jackson-version-is-too-old)

For me, using Spark 2.x, adding the following to your `build.sbt` ensure the correct version is used:

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.6.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.6.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.5"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps.. :)